# Exclude SVN files from jar in maven

Tags: maven-2

in my project when I build it via the standard:

```
mvn clean package
```

I can see subversion specific files when inspecting the generated jar file. If I unzip the jar the content looks like:

```
myApp.jar
 |- _svn     <- subversion files
 |- com      <- my classes
 |- META-INF 
 |- some.xml <- some configuration
 ...
```

I would like to exclude the `_svn` folder from all my generated jars. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Why do use _svn and not the default .svn ?

Comment: Unsure, I didn't change this intentionally, this is how I checked out the project from SVN with IntelliJ 11 ...

Comment: That must be done intentionally, cause SVN has the default ".svn" instead of "_svn". Have you checked out the project via TortoiseSVN ? Changed the configuration there ?